# html only form that spits out a text block "mad libs"

Tags: html

Maybe I just don't know how to ask the question, but I can't find anything online that doesn't use Javascript or something else to create what I'm trying to do.

All I want is to use simple simple html with a few input text fields to take user submitted data and then spit out a chunk of text combining their input with already existing text when they click a button, kinda like a mad lib.

Is that possible in html only?

Comment: html forms normally have a destination such as `<form action="/action_page.php">` where you are taken to a page for processing.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **Not Possible**

HTML in itself is a static language, Meaning - It does not change.

You would need to use at least one of the following (or combination) to modify contents on a webpage:

- Back-end language (PHP/ASP..etc.)
- Front-end script (JS/VBScript..etc.)